# Run a loop for each row in R

Tags: r, row

I have been trying hard (as a beginner) to do this. I have a text where I would like to have some parts replaced with the row entries of a data frame (or matrix if that is easier).
I have an example dataset as follows:

```
   x      y      z
1  5  apple  green
2  7 banana yellow
3 13  mango    red
```

I am stuck at this:

```
for (x in mydata[["x"]]) {
    for (y in mydata[["y"]]) {
        for (z in mydata[["z"]]) {
            print(paste("The year is", x, y,"color", z))
        }
    }
}
```

However this renders texts with all possible combinations.
I want to get:

```
"The year is 5 apple color green"
"The year is 7 banana color yellow"
"The year is 13 mango color red"
```

I have tried repeat, for, if, while but I get either the first, the last or an all combination return.
How can I define that I only want a sentence per row?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't need a loop for this as `paste` is vectorized.

```
paste("This year is", df1$x, df1$y, "color", df1$z)
```

Or use `sprintf`

```
sprintf("This year is %s %s color %s", df1$x, df1$y, df1$z)
```

Or without calling 'df1' 3 times

```
do.call(sprintf, c(df1, fmt = "This year is %s %s color %s")) 
#[1] "This year is 5 apple color green"   "This year is 7 banana color yellow"
#[3] "This year is 13 mango color red"
```

---

The OP's post used a nested `for` loop, so we got all the combinations instead of the expected.  We can loop over the sequence of rows, use that as index to extract the elements of each column and `paste` it.

```
for(i in seq_len(nrow(df1))){
   print(paste("This year is", df1$x[i], df1$y[i], "color", df1$z[i]))
 } 
#[1] "This year is 5 apple color green"
#[1] "This year is 7 banana color yellow"
#[1] "This year is 13 mango color red"
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(x = c(5L, 7L, 13L), y = c("apple", "banana", "mango"
), z = c("green", "yellow", "red")), .Names = c("x", "y", "z"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding a solution only because the `apply` family of functions has not been mentioned yet.

My one line solution:

```
df = data.frame(x=c(5,7,13), y = c('apple', 'banana','mango'), z = c('green', 'yellow', 'red'))

apply(df,1, function(a) paste("This year is", a[1], a[2], "color", a[3]) )
```

Which gives:

```
[1] "This year is  5 apple color green"
[2] "This year is  7 banana color yellow"
[3] "This year is 13 mango color red"
```

Also, printing the output one row at a time is easy with:

```
writeLines(paste(...))
```